# Live television and plosive popping

Tags: plosives, tv-show

I watched a major television sporting event last night and was surprised at the amount of plosive popping.  The announcements within the stadium suffered from the effect as well as the programme presenters and commentators.

Plosive popping is so easily dealt with.  Do you think the audience notices, or has plosive popping become an indicator of a live rather than a recorded event, giving the audience confidence that there is no delay in broadcast?

Answer (score 2):

I really think that a lot of people just tune that stuff out...it's somewhat surprising to me, though, that so many people whose job it is to speak into microphones all the time have never learned to speak PAST the mic as opposed to INTO...but, again, I guess it's that tuning out....people really tune out a surprising number of things.